# torrent lens not working

Tags: lenses

I have just installed the torrent lens on ubuntu 12.04 and it returns no matches for any keyword. I may have installed it incorrectly, but how can I check? i am new to Ubuntu and linux, only having installed it a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

you should have mentioned the installation instructions. any way , if you did not followed this method , then please do reinstallation with this method and let us know

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-lens-torrents unity-scope-piratebay
```